# How to use dynamic ApiSecret in securing an api with IdentityServer middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm securing an API with the IdentityServer middle-ware talking to an identity server.

In the API I have code similar to:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
        options.Authority = identityServerSettings.AuthorityUri;
        options.ApiName = identityServerSettings.ApiName;
        options.ApiSecret = secret;
    }
);
```

I want to setup the middle-ware with an `ApiSecret`, but I want to get this secret from hashicorp's vault. 
I want to configure the middle-ware so that it retrieves a values and sets the ApiSecret on each request.

Something like:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
        options.Authority = identityServerSettings.AuthorityUri;
        options.ApiName = identityServerSettings.ApiName;
        options.ApiSecret = () => GetSecret();
    }
);
```

The intention for this would be to enable service restart-less key rotation by hashicorp's vault.

Both this API and the IdentityServer would request the secret from vault and this would allow the rotation of secrets without the restarting of the API or IdentityServer services.

Is this possible? How would one do it?

Comment: What exactly you think you would win if you did that? No, it's not possible because it doesn't make any sense

Comment: to add what @CamiloTerevinto mentioned, these are configuration settings that runs when the app is 'startup'not for every request.

Comment: You don't win anything. The API Secret is to verify that the API is a trusted one. Even if you could do this, you would need to update Identity Server's database to set the new value. In the worst case that you lose the key, you can just disable the API while generating a new one

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.

Comment: I misunderstood the intention of the ticket i'm working on and have updated the question. I'd be grateful if you have any ideas on this.

Comment: The first thing to establish is whether you actually need a secret at all. I believe the only use case for it is the introspection endpoint which is only really needed if using reference tokens. As for resolving the secret on every request - I suspect you'd need to customise the middleware to support this but it's by no means impossible.